# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, sql, excepciones, nullpointerexception, null

Estoy generando este código:

```
public void llenarTabla(){
    this.modelSalon = new DefaultTableModel(){
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int colum){
    return false;
    }
    };
    this.modelSalon.setColumnCount(0);
    this.modelSalon.addColumn("Num_Salon");
    this.modelSalon.addColumn("Cant_Camas");
    this.modelSalon.addColumn("area");
    this.modelSalon.addColumn("cedula_doctor");
    List<Salones> lista = this.salBo.consultaTodos();
    this.modelSalon.setNumRows(lista.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            Salones sal = lista.get(i);
            this.modelSalon.setValueAt(sal.getNum_salon(), i, 0);
            this.modelSalon.setValueAt(sal.getCant_camas(), i, 1);
            this.modelSalon.setValueAt(sal.getArea(), i, 2);
            Doctor doc = this.docBo.consultaXCedula(sal.getCedula_doctor());
            this.modelSalon.setValueAt(doc.getCedula(), i, 3);
        }
        this.TableSalon.setModel(modelSalon);

    }
```

Pero me envía el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at ventanas.ManteSalon.llenarTabla(ManteSalon.java:81)  at
>   ventanas.ManteSalon.(ManteSalon.java:59)    at
>   ventanas.ManteSalon$7.run(ManteSalon.java:449)    at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   BUILD STOPPED (total time: 16 minutes 46 seconds)

Lo he revisado, he limpiado el programa y demás, ¡pero el problema persiste! dentro del 'sql' si existe información dentro de esos campos. ¿Podrían orientarme?

Gracias.

Comment: Muestra el código donde creas el objeto `modelSalon` y donde llamas al método `llenarTabla()`.

Comment: private DefaultTableModel modelSalon; esta seria la sentencia para la declaracion

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el detalle es que creas el modelo de la tabla, luego creas las columnas pero no la añades a la tabla sino despues de intentar agregar los datos por lo que para ese momento la estructura de la tabla aun no existe. Es null.

> this.TableSalon.setModel(modelSalon);

colocalo despues de:

> this.modelSalon.addColumn("cedula_doctor");

Comment: Hice el cambio pero brindo el mismo error!

Comment: Haz algo, coloca o resalta la linea que da el error.

Comment: ventanas.ManteSalon.llenarTabla(ManteSalon.java:81)